# Jeditable text area width

Tags: jquery, html, jeditable

i am using jeditable http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/4/autogrow-textarea-for-jeditable

Here is the code for the same

```
    $('.serisC').editable('series_edit_ajax.php',{
                        type      : 'textarea',

                        id        : 'elementid',
                        name      : 'newvalue',
                        event     : "dblclick",
                        cancel    : 'Cancel',
                        submit    : 'OK',                           
                        indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
                        tooltip   : 'Double Click to edit...',
                        style     : 'width:50px',
                    });
```

The above code does not change the text area width what will be the reason . An  immediate response is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is not supposed to change the width of the text area but its height.
Anyway, you didn't even tell jeditable to use the plugin, read the documentation you linked to again.